# How to convert windows phone 7 xap file to windows phone 8 xap?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I have windows phone 7 xap file, when I try to deploy it on my wp8 device, it gave me an error.I don't have project files. Is there another way?

Comment: right click on your project / change windows phone version build / correct error and recreate xap

Comment: @MatDevWp8 users doesn't have project file. Then, how can upgrade to WP8 using Solution Explorer in VS ?

Comment: @user2735149: all WP7 apps will work on WP8 devices. can you please mention what error it shows ? But please mind, you cant upgrade WP7 app into Wp8 app without have project files.!